# Can PPL, CPL, and ATPL be completed within a year?

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-training, general-aviation, pilot-certification, south-africa

It took me about 8 months to complete my PPL, because I struggled to go solo and I haven't started my CPL training yet due to financial set back.

I've heard about students who completed their PPL training in 2 months.

Is it possible to complete PPL, CPL and Frozen ATPL in 12 months and how do you go about it? And also, are there any cases? The one I've seen is 18 months.

Considering the fact that you have to write CPL exams, ATPL exams, IR, Night Rating, 100 PIC hours and other related tasks.

Comment: About the biggest setback in my part of the world was always the weather. When training for my PPL I swear I spent more time looking at the sky from the ground, than actually in the air.

Comment: Which country/regulator are you asking about?

Comment: Only fact I can guess is he is from South Africa.

Comment: My question is based on South African regulations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the hours required for the ATP, the chance of doing that rating alone in under a year seems pretty remote.

Getting the private and commercial certificates done inside of a year is entirely possible, although not cheap. The writtens for the ATP are no big deal, but the hours simply will take a lot of time, as well as the right employment opportunity, to get.

The number of FO's at smaller (regional) airlines who have been flying for several years but who don't yet have their ATP attests to the time required. You can (and generally have to) pay for the flight time to get your Commercial, but paying for all the flight time required for an ATP is simply beyond those of whose last name isn't Gates, Bezos, Trump, or etc.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean frozen ATPL? This can be easily done in 3 months if you have unlimited money and normal intellectual qualities.